# How to add image from gallery to WordPress theme's footer template?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

```
<footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container">
     // add image from gallery
        <p>&copy;   2011-<?php echo date_i18n("Y") ?></p>

    </div> <!-- / END CONTAINER -->

</footer>
```

How to form url for footer? I want that my footer image will be displayed in any host. How to set up base url for my images from /uploads folder.

--edit

```
<img src=<?php echo site_url() ."/image/img.png";?></img>
```

Is this good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe?

`<img src="<?php echo content_url(); ?>/uploads/image/img.png" />`